# C# и БД SQL

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sql

Здравствуйте! у меня есть база данных в SQL и выводится она вся в visual studio, на С# там все написано...

процедура по удалению строки в БД работает, а вот в студии нет! при нажатии на кнопку ничего совсем не происходит, даже ошибок никаких... может посоветуете где примерно это можно посмотреть?

код кнопки такой

```
*private void button12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (PlanListDataGridView.SelectedRows != null)
            {
                int id = (int)PlanListDataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value;

                PlanList.DeletePlan(id);

                PlanListBindingSource.DataSource = PlanList.GetPlanList();
            }
        }*
```

Comment: PlanList.Fill()

Answer (score 1):

Если `PlanList` - это что-то типа `DataSet`, то, вероятно нужно ещё вызвать метод `Update` у адаптера данных.

Answer (score 1):

Вы удаляете из таблицы, а надо бы из источника данных удалить. Тогда данные в таблице  и обновятся.

Comment: PlanList скорее всего адаптер. Просто его надо скорее всего перегрузить.